# .net 6 console app running old signalr server

Tags: signalr, .net-6.0

Currently trying to build old SignalR server for legacy SignalR clients already in use by many clients. But we want to try to build project with later version (i.e. .NET 6) for many reasons.

I know there are people out there who claim they were able to use new .NET Core SignalR server to talk to old SignalR clients, however I want to stick to what Microsoft claims: "ASP.NET Core SignalR isn't compatible with clients or servers for ASP.NET SignalR. This article details features which have been removed or changed in ASP.NET Core SignalR."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-7.0

If there is anybody done this way (using new .NET Core project for old SignalR server to be compatible to old SignalR clients), please shine me some lights.

I am stuck at trying to port over old OWIN code to .NET Core project and it doesn't necessarily have to be this way although if people who already worked on this got it working on this path, that would be great.

Comment: I have the same issue in my current project.